# POST request with Authorization

Tags: angular

Instead of returning me data why does it say Object `{status: 200, message: "Key Missing", data: null}` in the console

Here's my service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
    export class GetValueService {
        constructor(private http: Http){
            console.log('Init');
        }

        getValue(){
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append( 'Authorization', 'afkdihnadbufgadbg325423' )
            return this.http.post('url', { headers: headers }).map(response => response.json())
        }
    }
```

Here's the component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GetValueService } from '../../services/getvalue/getValue.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'selectValue',
    templateUrl: 'selectValue.component.html',
    providers: [GetValueService ]
})
export class selectValueComponent  {
    constructor(private getValueService : GetValueService ){

        this.getValueService.getValue().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })

    }
}
```

I did read the documentation and there aren't any great tutorials on this. I don't get what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: please look up the documentation for the http.post method.  You're calling it with the wrong parameters

Comment: Post real code. And check the code or documentation of "it". We can't possibly say why an unknown backend sends a response to an unknown request.

Answer (score 0):

```
post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>;
```

This is the way you should post data in Angular.